# Sagepay token system delete token

Tags: api, token, opayo

I'm using Sage Pay token system, evrithyng is working fine I store the tokens on my side. The question is if I want to remove a token is it fine to remove it only from my side, and then if some one wants to add tha card again to create another token or I have to send a request to sagepay with StoreToken = 0 param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the token from your side only, but I would recommend sending a REMOVETOKEN request to Sage Pay to remove it (or setting StoreToken=0 on usage) - token storage is charged above a certain threshold. No point paying for something you can't use.....

Your end user can create another token if required.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code:

```
# REMOVE TOKEN REQUEST
if(YourCondition=='OK')
{
    $strRemoveTokenURL = "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/removetoken.vsp";
    $sToken = 'Token Stored your side';
    $strPost = "VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=REMOVETOKEN&Vendor=yourvendorid&Token=".$sToken;
    $arrRemoveResponse = requestPost($strRemoveTokenURL, $strPost);
}

# REMOVE TOKEN RESPONSE
echo '<hr>';
print"<pre>";print_r($arrRemoveResponse);print"<pre>";
exit;
```

Comment: Is there any API reference for REMOVETOKEN?